# JQuery,Spring MVC Dynamically loading select options for city district on Registration form

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I have a jsp form like this... Values in the second select box, District should be loaded based on value in first select box (state),. I am using jQuery, Spring MVC to retrieve results.but for that i first required value of stateId in my controller and this value not getting in my controller

addEmployee.jsp

```html
<form:form id="employeeForm" modelAttribute="personaladdress" method="post" action="${baseURL}employee/save" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">state</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <form:select path="stateId" id="state">
        <form:option value="" label="--Select State--"></form:option>
        <c:forEach var="list" items="${states}">
          <option value="${list.stateId }">${list.stateName }</option>

        </c:forEach>
      </form:select>
      <form:errors path="stateId"></form:errors>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form:select path="districtId" id="district">
    <form:option value="" label="--select District--"></form:option>
    <form:options items="${districtList}" itemValue="districtid" itemLabel="description"></form:options>
  </form:select>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addemployee",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addEmployee( @ModelAttribute("personalinformation") PersonalInformation personalinformation,
        @ModelAttribute("personaladdress")PersonalAddress personaladdress,
        @ModelAttribute("employee")Employee employee,BindingResult result,Model model){ 
       model.addAttribute("personalinformation",new PersonalInformation());
         model.addAttribute("employee",new Employee());
         model.addAttribute("personaladdress",new PersonalAddress());
         List<State>list=iEmployeeService.getStateList();
         model.addAttribute("states",list); 

       return "addEmployee";    
}

@RequestMapping(value="/districtList",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 @ResponseBody List<District> getDistrictList(@ModelAttribute("personalinformation") PersonalInformation personalinformation,
         @RequestParam(value="stateId", required=true) String stateId, Model model){
    System.out.println("inside districtlistst");
    System.out.println("inside districtlist"+stateId);
     List<District>list=iEmployeeService.getDistrictList();
    return list;
}
```

Jquery function..

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$('select#state').change(function() {
  var MSG=$("#state").val();
  alert(MSG);
   $.post("employee?action=districtList", {
    stateId: MSG
  }
  ,
  function(data) {
    alert("sucess");
  }
  );
```

i have registration form of employee in this i have to display Drop-down list of state,district and city dynamically.i have done with the Statelist but i am unable to get the id of selected state in my controller so then i can return a district list my form containing employee fields,personal information and personal address so that i have created two methods first returns string and displays registration page with state dropdown and another method for ditrict list but in jquery function i get the id but in getDistrictList method iam unable to get id.please suggest me what to do 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using post type ajax and your spring controller method accepts the get request.

Try something like this :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```